# How to send base64 image vie http Post request?

Tags: c#, http-post

i am creating application that sends image to web server and i have some problem with the code:
Here is the example from website:

```
    Get your API key from your account settings page. Each user is given a unique authentication token, we call it API key. It's a 32-characters string that looks like:2abc234de56fab7c89012d34e56f6789
This key will be used for all your requests to our server.
Submit a HTTP POST request to our API URL: http://azcaptcha.com/in.php with parameters corresponding to the type of your captcha.
Server will return captcha ID or an error code if something went wrong.
Make a timeout: 20 seconds for ReCaptcha, 5 seconds for other types of captchas.
Submit a HTTP GET request to our API URL: http://azcaptcha.com/res.php to get the result.
If captha is already solved server will return the answer in format corresponding to the type of your captcha.
By default answers are returned as plain text like: OK|Your answer. But answer can also be returned as JSON {"status":1,"request":"TEXT"} if json parameter is used.
If captcha is not solved yet server will return CAPCHA_NOT_READY result. Repeat your request in 5 seconds.
If something went wrong server will return an error code.
```

and here is the Base64 sample form

```
<form method="post" action="http://azcaptcha.com/in.php">
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="base64">
Your key:
<input type="text" name="key" value="YOUR_APIKEY">
The CAPTCHA file body in base64 format:
<textarea name="body">BASE64_FILE</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Upload and get the ID">
</form>
```

but when i tryed to send it i get error from server that base64 file is unreadable,but if i send it via HTML page with the code from base64 sample it works , so here is and my C# code:

```
byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Cvetan Tokov\Desktop\New folder\rep.png");
            string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
            richTextBox1.Text = base64ImageRepresentation;
           
             string key = "MY API KEY";
             ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
             string postData = richTextBox1.Text;

             byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
             WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://azcaptcha.com/in.php?key=MY API KEY&method=base64");
             request.Method = "post";
            
             request.ContentType = "text/html; charset=windows-1252";

            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

             using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
             {
                 stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
             }
```

this code didn't send base64 string in correct order to be read from server
can someone help me to create the form from example in C# .

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Try : request.ContentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use a web sniffer. For example, HTTP Analyzer. Turn it on, send a request through browser and through your app, and then compare what is the difference - mainly see "Headers" and "Post data" tabs.

Comment: Thanks , i have tryed and see the difference but still not sure how to edit C# code to perform this task,the problem is that there is different HEADERS and FORM VALUES ,